# Retrieve Value From DropdownList into controller

Tags: c#, .net, forms, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am currently trying to populate a dropdownlist(or asp-net select, doesn't really matter, whichever works) so that I can grab whatever value they had selected, and do some manipulation in the controller.

The issue comes in to play when it comes to defining these values. These values can be hard coded because it's not pulling from anything and they will remain the same. However, I also need to reference these values via a model so I can do something like this

```
public IActionResult Example(ModelName model) {
var selectedValue = model.Id // Or model.Name

Do manipulation here...
}
```

So the bottom line question is, where do I define these values, and how do I send the selected values back to a model so I can manipulate them in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Select Select { get; set; }
}
public class Select
{
    public int SelectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

```
@model TestModel
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Example">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Select.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Select.SelectId" asp-items="ViewBag.SList"></select>                    
                <span asp-validation-for="Select.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

3.Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Select> selectList = new List<Select>()
        {
            new Select(){  SelectId=1, Name="aaa"},
            new Select(){  SelectId=2, Name="bbb"},
            new Select(){  SelectId=3, Name="ccc"},
            new Select(){  SelectId=4, Name="ddd"},
        };
        ViewBag.SList = new SelectList(selectList, "SelectId", "Name");
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Example(TestModel model)
    {
        var selectedValue = model.Select.SelectId;// Or model.Name
        //do your stuff...
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Luckily I got it to work before seeing this, but it's pretty identical to what I have. Minus the ViewBag and I used a DropdownListFor