# Return State and city on Drop down list in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, dropdown, viewdata, jquery-selectbox

I Created a form on my Asp.core project.Now I want to add a drop down list for show states and city on that form.

I create  a model and view model:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public long? ParentId { get; set; }


    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

and write some method to access it on my repository and service:

Repository:

```
  public async Task<List<UserLocationViewModel>> GetStateForUserInfo()
    {
        return await _context.Locations.Where(l => l.ParentId == null)
            .Select(l => new UserLocationViewModel()
            {
                Title = l.Title,

            }).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<UserLocationViewModel>> GetCityForUserInfo(long locationId)
    {
      return await _context.Locations.Where(l => l.ParentId == locationId)
            .Select(l => new UserLocationViewModel()
            {
                Title = l.Title,

            }).ToListAsync();
    }
```

and service:

```
    public async Task<List<UserLocationViewModel>> GetStateForUserInfo()
    {
       return await _packageRepository.GetStateForUserInfo();
    }

    public async Task<List<UserLocationViewModel>> GetCityForUserInfo(long locationId)
    {
        return await _packageRepository.GetCityForUserInfo(locationId);
    }
```

then on controller I call these method and return to view with view data:

```
  ViewData["State"] = _packageService.GetStateForUserInfo();
     
  ViewData["City"] = _packageService.GetCityForUserInfo(packageId);
```

in view I call it :

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = _localizer["GetUserInfo"];
IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel> State = ViewData["State"] as IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel>;
IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel> city = ViewData["City"] as IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel>;
```

}

But when I want to access it on select tag I cant access to my properties:

```
                            <select   asp-for= "?????"   class="form-control  ">
                             
                            </select>
```

---

[image]

---

UPDATE:
First read my repository to get location Id:
but I have error

then in controller I need the id so I write:

```
var firstLocationId = state.FirstOrDefault()?.Id;
        var city = await _packageService.GetCityForUserInfo(firstLocationId);
        ViewData["City"] = new SelectList(city, "Title", "Title");
```

Comment: Hi @hasti.au, `asp-items` is used to store select list items. `asp-for` is used to map the value if you post the selected value to backend. I think you need check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60312170/11398810). Besides, did you use any jquery plugin?

Comment: Ok I add Asp-items. but how can input find which property is for it? I mean what about asp-for? I cant find any property for asp-for ,It does not know any property on new view model

Comment: `asp-for` depends on what's the property value you want to post to the backend. Please share more info.

Comment: I share all of thing. this page has another view model. after finish task I decide to add a drop down list for city and stat. so I create a new model (Location Model). I want to find city and state. On controller, I had to choose from my view model or Select List?

Comment: I mean, did you want to post selected city or state to controller ? If you need, `asp-for` is necessary. For example, you want to get the CityId of the City,so you need add CityId in ViewModel and use `asp-for="CityId"`. If you do not want to post selected city or state to controller. Just for display the two dropdownlist, `asp-for` is no need.

Comment: Besides, did you want to display one dropdownlist by combing City and State?

Comment: I want to display drop down on page ,but I create just one table for both state and city with id and parent id .I write method and want to use it on controller then pass them to view.(With view data because page has another view model)

Comment: Ok. Maybe in a mess here. I share a sample about how to display dropdownlist below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample you could follow:

Model:

```
public class UserLocationViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }     //if you do not need post selected city or state
    public string State { get; set; }   //it is no need add these two properties
}
public class Location
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

View:

For `public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);`, the first parameter is the source, the second parameter is each option value in select, the third parameter is that each option displays text in html.

[image]

```
@model UserLocationViewModel
@{
    IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel> State = ViewData["State"] as IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel>;
    IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel> city = ViewData["City"] as IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel>;
}

<select asp-items="@(new SelectList(State,"Title","Title"))" class="form-control">
</select>

<select  asp-items="@(new SelectList(city,"Title","Title"))" class="form-control">
</select>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewData["State"] = _packageService.GetStateForUserInfo();    
    ViewData["City"] = _packageService.GetCityForUserInfo(packageId);
    return View();
}
```

If you want to post the selected city or state to controller:

Index.cshtml:

The mapped property in `asp-for` should be the same type with `dataValueField`(`Title` here).

```
@model UserLocationViewModel
@{
    IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel> State = ViewData["State"] as IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel>;
    IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel> city = ViewData["City"] as IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel>;
}
<form method="post">
    <select asp-for="State" asp-items="@(new SelectList(State,"Title","Title"))" class="form-control">
    </select>

    <select asp-for="City" asp-items="@(new SelectList(city,"Title","Title"))" class="form-control">
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    ViewData["State"] = _packageService.GetStateForUserInfo();     
    ViewData["City"] = _packageService.GetCityForUserInfo(packageId);
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(UserLocationViewModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

### Update:

Two ways display dropdownlist:

First one:

```
ViewData["State"] = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{Text = "Value1", Value = "1"},
    new SelectListItem{Text = "Value2", Value = "2"},
    new SelectListItem{Text = "Value3", Value = "3"},
    new SelectListItem{Text = "Value4", Value = "4"}
}
```

Razor view:

```
<select asp-items="(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)@ViewData["State"]" class="form-control">
</select>
```

Second one:

```
ViewData["State"] = await Locations.Where(l => l.ParentId == null)
                                    .Select(l => new UserLocationViewModel()
                                    {
                                        Title = l.Title,

                                    }).ToListAsync();
```

Razor view:

```
@{
IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel> State = ViewData["State"] as IEnumerable<UserLocationViewModel>;   
 }
<select asp-items="@(new SelectList(State,"Title","Title"))" class="form-control">
</select>
```

Comment: I update my controller. My index method has another method. I do all of things that you said. but this is result. and still I cant use asp-for. because does not know location view model properties. I use from view model on repository and service. should I use from Select Item List?

Comment: Hi @hasti.au, your backend code is useless actually. Just make sure the two ViewData contain value is ok. `and still I cant use asp-for` please share what is the error. What is your razor view now?

Comment: To be confirmed if you do not need to post the dropdownlist, no need using `asp-for`. `asp-for` is used to model binding when you post from view to controller.

Comment: Also, check my model, I have  `State` and `City` property in my model. And then I use `asp-for="State"` and `asp-for="City"` in the view. Please read my answer more carefully. If any question, please edit your question and share with us, do not just say does not work. What is the error you need to share with us.

Comment: I read all of them carefully. first of all tell me should I use with location view model on repository or <List<SelectItemList>? I cannot second one because It does not know it.

Comment: What is List<SelectItemList>? Did you mean `List<SelectListItem>`? I have update a new simple demo. I guess you misunderstand `SelectList` and `SelectListItem`.

Comment: And why not share your razor view with us? If you could share with it, we will not be stucked in  guessing what is the error you are facing.

Comment: Thank you so much . Now it is Ok . Really I apricate you

Comment: I have another problem. Now I have 2 table. first" user info " that have information of my user. another" location" is state and city. They have relation. Should I add city and state to my model (table of user info ) too? Because I want to have state and city of mu user. Or because of their relation, does not need to add city to table of user info?

Comment: I insert location Id on table for use state and city. Now my problem is to get location Id. in this method on controller, because i need to return id :
 I Update my question. please check it

Comment: Hi @hasti.au, Cannot reproduce the issue, what is your error message? If the original issue has been solved, please remember to accept as answer. You could post a new thread to ask question.